# Spring MVC : Scheduled method not autofiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I would periodically require to get the onlineUsers to persist them in the database. I checked on net and I can use @Scheduled from Spring to achieve this task. I have written a method, but it does not seem to auto-fire. I have no error log, as the method does not autofire, but the program compiles normally. I just don't see the output in console. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Here goes my code :

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void listUsers(){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
        List<Person> usersInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object principal: principals) {
            if (principal instanceof Person) {
                for(SessionInformation sess :sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false)){
                    if(!sess.isExpired()){
                        usersInfoList.add((Person) sess.getPrincipal());
                        System.out.println("Logged in users are "+((Person) sess.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I have also made changes in session management in security-application-context to get non-expired sessions like this :

```
<security:session-management>
     <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login"/>
 </security:session-management>

<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot... :-)

*Edit*

sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() returns :

```
Session registry all sessions is [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dde5c0af: Username: user@email.de; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER]
```

It does not enter the code where I want the sessions are not expired.

```
   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
// it does not enter in below for loop.
         for(SessionInformation sess :sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false)){
                            System.out.println("Logged in users are "+((Person) sess.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
                    }
```

Any idea what might be wrong??

Comment: P.S : I presume,  @Scheduled with fixedRate fires automatically and I don't need to call the method for first time.

Comment: Have you enabled scheduling using `@EnableScheduling` annotation?

Comment: @Mithun  Thanks. Please post your comment as answer too so I can accept. . That was the mistake, by the way, can you also tell me if there is any mistake in the code, as it does not reach till System.out.println(). There are 2 logged in users currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Schedluing because by default spring doesn't enable scheduling support. You can do it using  `@EnableScheduling` which Enables Spring's scheduled task execution capability, similar to functionality found in Spring's  XML namespace

Comment: Thank you for the answer. User Mithun already answered that in comments. Can you tell me why I am not getting logged in users, as it does not go in the System.out.println().

Comment: I will suggest you first to turn on spring security debugging (in log4j.properties add log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG), it helps in debugging.  Can you also checks what `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() `  returns

Comment: I have edited the main post, can you please check it. It returns the email, but does not enter into the for loop.

Comment: @WeareBorg seems `sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false)`  returning empty list, that's why `for-loop` is not executed. Could you try to change `max-sessions="1"` to for e.g. `max-sessions="10"`

Comment: Did it, no change... :-(